# IDEA intellij character support

Tags: eclipse, fonts, github, intellij-idea

Is there a way to change character support in IntelliJ?

Between working with IntelliJ/Eclipse/github, I have bullet used in a some lines of text that is causing an annoyance.

Eclipse shows the bullet fine, as does github, but when I pull the file down into an intelliJ environment the bullet is replaced with an unkown symbol.

• => �

Now when I copy-pasta that bullet mark off of github's web viewer into the file, it looks, works, and compiles fine. Upon committing to github, the bullet then changes to another set of characters, then making me have to fix it again.

• => â€¢

Thoughts on how I can avoid having to always fix this when switching between environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the file has correct encoding and [IDE is configured](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-encodings.html) to create new files in the desired encoding.

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't provide a seamless way to convert between different encodings, so if your file already has incorrect encoding, you will need to convert it in some other tool.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder. It was a clash between unsupported characters from other developers environments.